# What is the benefit of computing age of an object?

Tags: java, object, garbage-collection, jvm, singleton

- Stumbled upon a question which was related to Calendar object in stackoverflow. Reading this question led me to ask myself one question : *'What if we are able to find age of an object? Age of an object in terms of hours/days/weeks/months/years. And what can do we do with that? Would it be helpful at all? Will it help me to analyze my program runtime? '*
- I guess we can relate to age of objects for singleton objects, since it exists during the lifetime of the application. In the sense that, from the time, singleton object is loaded, it starts its life and ends life, when application ends. But the same could be extended to non-singleton objects as well.
- I assumed that this question might be worthwhile pursuing, but I wanted to confirm from stackoverflow community. Do you think we might encounter a scenario in runtime of application/system, where we need to compute age of an object in JVM or runtime memory etc. By computing which, we could make some decisions for application.
- After some small research, found that Garbage-Collector needs to be aware of age of objects.

So, what I would like to know is the following:

1. What if we are able to find age of an object? Age of an object in terms of hours/days/weeks/months/years. And what can do we do using that?
2. Would it be helpful at all?
3. Will it help us to analyze my program runtime and do something with that and what would it be?
4. What is a probable/possible part of application runtime/scenario which might benefit from computing age of an object?
5. Have you encountered a scenario during your development/debugging/field-issues wherein you hoped that if it was able to compute age of an object, it would have benefitted?

(Hopefully, this might not get downvoted, just want to add that I was curious to ask stackoverflow community. Apologize that this is not a programming exercise which fits to be asked here. Have added tags for bringing context to this question.)

Comment: Read up on [generational garbage collection](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GenerationalGarbageCollection).

Comment: thanks, will read it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the benefit would be.  I suppose, it might help with certain performance tuning and debugging problems.

However, there is no practical way to do this (in standard Java) unless the object is coded to record its own age.  And that would have significant time and space costs.

---

> After some small research, found that Garbage-Collector needs to be aware of age of objects.

Actually, a generational GC only needs the approximate age.  It can determine that based on where the object currently lives; i.e. what "space" it is currently allocated in.

---

For the Java language and mainstream implementations ...

> What if we are able to find age of an object?

We can't, in general.  This makes the remaining questions "moot", generally speaking.

> And what can do we do using that?

Moot.

> Would it be helpful at all?

Moot.

> Will it help us to analyze my program runtime and do something with that and what would it be?

In some cases, possibly yes.  However the question is moot.

> What is a probable/possible part of application runtime/scenario which might benefit from computing age of an object?

Possibly performance tuning.  Possibly debugging.  However the question is moot.

> Have you encountered a scenario during your development/debugging/field-issues wherein you hoped that if it was able to compute age of an object, it would have benefitted?

Possibly.  (I've been programming for 40+ years, and it is hard to remember everything I've done in that time period.)  However I didn't stress about it.

Also, I've never considered that benefits of (hypothetically) recording the lifetime of each and every object would be worth the cost.

But if you are designing / implementing a new experimental programming language, feel free to include this in the feature list.  If it turns out to be a useful feature<sup>1</sup>, there should be some research papers in it.

---

<sup>1 - and (cynically) even if not :-)</sup>

Comment: thanks. If I stumble upon designing a experimental language, will try this.